# Asymptotic approximations or upper bounds for ${}_{2}F_{1}(x+1,x+1,1,z)$ when $x \gg 1$?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I have recently encountered the hypergeometric function 
$$
{}_{2}F_{1}(x+1,x+1,1,z),
$$
where $x$ is an integer and $z$ is a real number with $x \ge 1$ and $0<z<1/2$. This is the first time I have dealt with this special function, most of the time I am dealing with Bessel and Hankel functions.

I am interested in approximations of the above function when $x$ is large. Are there any asymptotic approximations or upper bounds that I can use?

Comment: Here is a first guess. First one has to transform using the first equation of https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1 . After that one parameter goes to minus infinity while the other still goes to plus infinity. One should then be able to expanded asymptotically using http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.E5 .

Comment: My result is $_2F_1(1+x,1+x,1,z) \sim (\sqrt{2} z^{1/4} (1-z)^{x+\frac{1}{2}})^{-1}\sqrt{ arccosh{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}} I_{0}\left( (\frac{1}{2}+x)  arccosh(\frac{1+z}{1-z}) \right)$ which gives excellent numerical results for $z$ positive but well below 1.

Comment: @JohannesTrost That's interesting, actually my constraint on $z$ is $z < 1/2$. I have edited my post to reflect that. If you already have it coded up would you mind checking it for $z=1/2$ (worst case scenario) and $z=1/3$ (more common scenario? Otherwise I can check it later on my laptop when I get home, thanks.

Comment: $z=1/2$ is okay.The relative errors are about 0.03 for $z=1/2, x=1$ and about 0.006 for $z=1/2, x=10$. The relative error is of order $O(1/x)$.

Comment: Excellent thanks, its great to know highly accurate approximations are available for this function.

Comment: Hmmm, its a very good approximation but the $\text{arccosh}(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$ term is a bit unfortunate as it doesn't seem like there is a nice representation/approximation for it for $z \in (0,1/2)$. I am really only concerned with terms that decay/grow faster than algebraically so I can use $I_0(y) \le C e^y$ as $y\to \infty$ where $C$ contains the algebraic factors. But for $y=x \  \text{arccosh}(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$ I end up with $I_0(y) \le C e^{x \text{arccosh}(\frac{1+z}{1-z})}$ which doesn't give a clear indication of the behavior with respect to $z$.

Comment: Actually, I think this is fine in hindsight, the behavior with respect to $z$ and $x$ is very accurately characterized by the $e^{x z \text{arccosh}(\frac{1+z}{1-z})}$ function. Thanks again for the assistance.